# Java: Difference between Streams and I/O stream explained

Tags: java, java-8, inputstream, java-stream

I'm looking for a good explaination of the difference between the "new" Streams in Java 8 and the "old" I/O Streams we had before in Java 7. For someone without any knowledge of functional programming, it's hard to get that those are complete different things, especially because the names are the same. I get that the Stream API is something completely new and even revolutionary in some point, but in my naive thinking, in both cases we deal with sequences of "things", be it bytes, data or objects...

Can someone please offer a good explaination?

Comment: I/O streams are streams of data, bits and bytes from some source. The java8 streams are a way of traversing collections. They are used for completely different things.

Comment: You're asking use to compare a mechanism for applying methods to elements in some form of collection to the concept of writing (or reading) bytes. Those aren't really very similar concepts.

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is somehow too vague for me. Can this be somehow explained like, the one thing is a datastructure (?) and the other thing is... what?

Comment: *I/O streams* are for reading/writing bytes for Input/Output, mostly files and network sockets. The new *Streams* are for functional programming, mostly for processing Collections. They have nothing to do with each other, except an accidental **name conflict**.

Comment: "both deal with sequences of things, be it bytes, data or objects...". Right, there is no real difference on this abstract conceptual level. And I think this is the reason why both got named `streams`.

Answer (score 7):

It has nothing to do with each other and I agree, it's bad luck that IO Streams had their name before the "new" Streams have arrived. The I/O streams were meant as connections to external resources, mostly files, but also others. The new Streams are for functional programming and should be treated separately.

But you can actually use both concepts together. For example, a BufferedReader has a [lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--)-method, which returns lines of a file (or other resources) as a Stream of Strings.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at the picture illustrated I/O stream.

[image]

There are **three concerning concepts** related to I/O stream: **Source**, **Destination**, and **Element** (represented by the letter 'e'), where

- **Source** or **Destination** could by a file, network connection, pipe, memory buffer etc.
- An **Element** is just simply a piece of data and a **stream** consist of a chunk of elements

### When to use what?

**I/O streams** are for reading content from a source, or writing the content to a destination. That's it, simple :-)

**The new Stream concept introduced in Java 8 has nothing to do with I/O streams**. Streams are not themselves data structures, but Classes that allow you to manipulate a collection of data in a declarative way (functional-style operation).

Answer (score 3):

In term of 'stream' there is no difference. Stream is abstract phrase that means something that has a source and destination. What is more it is something that represents sequence of data.

In term of these two mechanism there is a lot of differences. For example Java i/o streams let you only read and write data. If you want to process data from that stream there is no builded in mechanism for that. In Java 8 stream there are additional possibilities of processig like map/filter etc.